# Select all visible occurrences of current selection in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode there's the "multi-caret replace" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) to select all occurrences of the current selection.

But is there a way to limit the scope of the multi-caret replace somehow, for example to the *current view* (visible lines)?

Or is the standard "single-caret replace" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>), "*find in selection*" the only option?

Comment: Does Ctrl+D not suit your purposes? You can tap it multiple times till you select everything in view.

Comment: But looking through here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings
Doesn't seem to be anything to select only visible occurences.

Comment: Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following key combination to add a highlight to each occurrence of the word: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

The command to do exactly what you want does not seem to exist [as shown in the documentation.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)